# How to use purgeCss with other module exports?

Tags: javascript, next.js, postcss, css-purge

I would like to use purgeCss in my NextJS project.
In the docs it says I should change my `next.config.js` to be like this:

```
module.exports = withCss(withPurgeCss())
```

But where do I set my current config?

```
module.exports = {
    distDir: '../.next',
    webpack: config => {
        const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'));
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

        return config;
    },
};
```

My postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "plugins": [
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
        [
            "postcss-preset-env",
            {
                "autoprefixer": {
                    "flexbox": "no-2009"
                },
                "stage": 3,
                "features": {
                    "custom-properties": false
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
            {
                content: [
                    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
                    './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
                ],
                defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
                safelist: ["html", "body"]
            }
        ],
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that since Next.js 9.3 you don't need to use `next-purgecss`. The configuration can be done fully via `postcss.config.js` ([reference](https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html#customize-postcss-configuration-next-js-9-3)).

Comment: Does that mean i dont need to do `withCss(withPurgeCss`?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config object goes inside the innermost plugin call.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = withCss(withPurgeCss({
    distDir: '../.next',
    webpack: config => {
        const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'));
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

        return config;
    },
}))
```

To solve your subsequent issue with the `postcss.config.js`, replace it with an object-based format (as indicated in [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#customizing-plugins) - it's right at the bottom of the page):

```js
module.exports = {
    'plugins': {
        'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
        'postcss-preset-env': {
            'autoprefixer': {
                'flexbox': "no-2009"
            },
            'stage': 3,
            'features': {
                'custom-properties': false
            }
        },
        '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss': {
            'content': [
                './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
                './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
            ],
            'defaultExtractor': content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            'safelist': ['html', 'body']
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it get this issue on build:
`TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]`

Comment: Can you show your `postcss.config.js` file? You can add it to your question.

Comment: Sure just added it to the question

Comment: Updated my answer for the postcss config issue.

Comment: ah i see thanks! That has got me a step further but as always the next issue I have ran into on build: `TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`

Comment: I'd suggest looking through Stackoverflow or raising a new question regarding that issue as it's falling outside of the scope of the original problem at this point.